# Identifying mystery dual channel opto detector?

Tags: components, identification, optoelectronics

How do I identify if a component is a photo diode or photo transistor? I have a three lead component removed from an old mouse where it was used to do quadrature encoding of the scroll wheel (a normal side facing IR LED was illuminating other side of the wheel) - presumably it houses two photo detectors side by side to distinguish which direction the wheel was being turned. What tests can I do to determine if it is a photo-transistor or photo-diode and appropriate parameters to drive it? I would like to re-purpose this for a micro-controller project I'm working on.

Only markings on the package is "H6.26" on the back and 'EL' on the top.

[Close up of the component - sorry, best I can do with 4am shed lighting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1oohj.jpg)

[In situ view - placed back from whence it came](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxl8I.jpg)

Managed to trace the two outer pins directly to separate pins on an unidentifiable micro-controller - (each trace is well below 1 Ohm). As for the middle pin it connects through a 10 Ohm resistor to I don't know where

Comment: Scope each pin and test with a pull-up R

Comment: How was it connected before you removed it?

Comment: Before removing it was connected to one of two three layer circuit boards with the traces disappearing in among 40 to 50 discreet components (was an old Dell bluetooth optical mouse).

Comment: please post a closeup picture

Comment: picture added - have been attempting to trace where the leads reemerge but it's a complete birds nest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Photodiode is a diode, phototransistor is a transistor. So take a DMM and measure diode forward voltage between all pins. If it's a diode, you will find one, if a transistor- two. I wonder what will you do with this information.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense now (it's been a long frustrating night/morning so probably didn't think things through as clearly as I should have) 0.59V between 1 and 2,  0.68V between 3 and 2 - I don't suppose it would be particularly important that the two diodes are perfectly matched unless dealing with extremely fast transitions. - I'm using the information to measure rotation of a brushed dc motor.

Comment: Buy an encoder. What you are doing is amateurish.

Comment: He is learning*

Comment: Not this way. Wasting his time is not effective for learning or for business.

Comment: I'd prefer to waist a night learning than a full week waiting for an encoder in the mail.

Comment: What im saying is that with such encoder on a motor you will not learn much anyway. But go ahead, you will come to same conclusion. Trust me, im only saying this out of experience.

Answer (score 3):

You've surmised that this is a phototransistor (detector). Since it is quadrature system, it may be a dual phototransistor (left), especially if the illuminating infra-red LED was a single emitter.
Which pin is which is unknown. You may have to try all combinations.
A test circuit is shown at right. Monitor the output while illuminating with an infra-red source. Unilluminated, the outputs should remain at +5V. A standard incandescent lightbulb should work as a source. The black plastic casing usually blocks visible light amazingly-well.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffbwWE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>